# How to console.log inside node_modules in NextJs?

Tags: next.js, node-modules

I am using NextJS version 12.1. I'm running my application locally with `next dev -p 3030`.

I'm trying to debug one node_module library behavior by adding some console.log inside of the module, but this don't change the results in my application. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

place `debugger` in the file and then replace `dev` script

```
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
```

then you need to start debug mode in vscode

proof of work:

[image]